# redirect user from server without client code

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api

I'm using fetch API to post a request to server:

```
function pay() {

    fetch('/pay', {
        method: 'post',
        redirect: 'follow',
        body: 'data sent'
    })
    .then(response => {
        // I need to redirect user from front-end here using code below
        if(response.redirected) {
            window.location.href = response.url;
        }
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
    
}
```

Then server responds to this request with a redirect like this:

```
res.redirect(`https://pay.ir/pg/${response.data.token}`);
```

The issue is this redirect doesn't work and I need to redirect user from front-end like what you see in the fetch function `window.location.href = response.url;`

How can I redirect user from server and not the client?

Answer (score 1):

The important thing to keep in mind here is that a redirect means "You asked for something, but you need to ask for it at this URL instead".

It does not mean "Navigate the main browser window to this URL".

---

If the user clicks a link then the browser will request the URL in the `href` attribute and navigate to it. If it gets a redirect response then it will navigate there instead.

If the user triggers some code which uses the `fetch` API then the browser will request the URL passed to `fetch` and pass the response to the `fetch` API. If it gets a redirect response then it will pass the response to following the redirect instead. (The `redirect` option to `fetch` can cause it to throw an error or have the author's JS handle it manually instead).

**There is no way for the response to override the browser's handling of it and cause navigation instead of being handled by the `fetch` API**.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly redirect the browser to another url, when you are hitting an api via Ajax call. 
The only way I can think of achieving this, is by using a form.

```html
<form action="/pay" method="POST">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John"><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Doe"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

<p>If you click the "Submit" button, the form-data will be sent to a page called "/pay" 
and it will follow through with the redirect response sent by the server.</p>
```

**OR** else you will have to return the URL to the front and redirect from the front end using `window.location.href='/somepath'`